# Error Installing Idle3.6

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

I am running Linux Mint 18.1 and python 3.6.

I would like to install idle3.6 but after installing [this package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/idle-python3.6)

i get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 4, in 
<module>
from tkinter import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in 
<module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for 
Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/idle3.6", line 3, in <module>
from idlelib.pyshell import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/idlelib/pyshell.py", line 7, in 
<module>
"Your Python may not be configured for Tk. **", file=sys.__stderr__)
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

what i understand is that i need to install the `tkinter` package.

what i have tried so far is this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

but it i still get the above error.

which command should i use to install tkinter for python 3.6?

Comment: did you ever get the answer to this? I'm having a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64562232/unable-to-import-tkinter-in-python3-but-it-works-in-python2-python3-7-macos-ca

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Linux Mint IDLE version: https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/idle-python3.5, since you are using Linux Mint. There's not yet a idle-python3.6 version.