# Unable to import tkinter in Python3, but it works in python2 (Python3.7 macOS Catalina)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-import, python-3.7

Running `python3` to bring me into python, and then simply running `import tkinter` results in the following error:

```
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

However when going into the `python` shell (not python3), `import tkinter` works fine as expected. How can I get tkinter to work with Python3?

Please note the following:

- I am on MacOS Catalina
- I am working with Python 3.7.3 (based off `python3 --version`)
- It looks like my python3 executable is (`/usr/bin/python3`)
- The path for tkinter is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/`
- I am able to run `idle` in Terminal, but I can't run `idle3`
- I don't think I am using a `virtualenv` or `pyenv` or anything like that

Comment: The python3 executable in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Python3 `  results in `exec format error`

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate Tcl/Tk installation. Try a newer version of the Python3 binary installer from python.org, which bundles Tcl/Tk.

Answer (score 0):

Don't install `tkinter` through `idle`. Try `idle3`. If nothing, install `python3-tk` using your OS installer. (I have `apt`. I'm on Debian.). Good luck!

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean? My terminal returns `command not found: idle3`. How can install tkinter through `idle3`?

Comment: You don't have it installed, I believe. Try searching up _how to install_ `idle3` _?_

Answer (score 0):

Don't use _ in `import _tkinter`

Use `import tkinter`

I am Sure that this will work. If it works then tick my answer.

Comment: I never ran `import _tkinter`, I simply ran `import tkinter`. By running `import tkinter`, if Python cannot import it, it automatically tries to `import _tkinter` itself, and if it can't do either it throws the error.

Comment: where are you writing the code on idle or python shell

Comment: Python3 shell in terminal (`python3` command in terminal, then trying to run `import tkinter` from there)

Answer (score -2):

Fist open Command Prompt and run `pip install tkinter`
Then open your python project and press Ctrl + S.
Then run your project.
I hope my answer is useful to you.

Comment: `tkinter` is a build in module, so you cannot  use `pip`. Output: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter`